# Работа с input type="date"

Tags: php, html, sql, timestamp

Создаю админ-панель и столкнулся с проблемой при реализации редактирования статьи.
Есть инпут с типом даты, в него нужно засунуть хотя бы дд.мм.гггг, не говоря уже о мм:чч. Вставляю в вэлью `value="<?=strtotime($article["date"])?>"`, как на одном примере и ничего не выводит, как видно на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Описание поля в БД: `date   timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Нет CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
Судя по-всему, в примере использовался тип `date`, а не как у меня, `timestamp`. Но все же, возможно ли как-то вывести дату в инпут? Идеально, конечно же, было бы и со временем.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5322285/4928642

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте через `value="<? date('ФОРМАТ', $article["date"])?>"` формат к примеру `d-m-Y`

мануал на [date](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: По идее, должно сработать так: `value="<?=date("d.m.Y", strtotime($article["date"]))?>"`, но нет.

Comment: Я так понимаю $article["date"] это данные из базы, значит вот так: value="<?=date("d.m.Y", $article["date"])?>"

Comment: Вот поверьте так value="<?=date('d-m-Y', time())?>"

Comment: Да, из БД. Не работает Ваш способ. Я думаю, это все из-за `timestamp`.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`orderdate`), '%d-%m-%Y') as "Date" вот тут та же проблема https://stackoverflow.com/a/15828652/5433400

Answer (score 0):

```
$article["date"] = '1589498254';

<input type='datetime-local' value='<?=date('Y-m-d',$article["date"] ).'T'.date('H:i',$article["date"])?>'/>
```

Comment: не знаю как я попал на этот вопрос спустя 3 года, но если что вот ответ

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/Kn1PTx

```
$x = 1634998633;
$val = date(DATE_ISO8601, $x);
echo "<input type=\"date\" value=\"$val\">";
```

```html
<input type="date" value="2021-10-23T14:17:13+0000">
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут 2 варианта записи:

В первом варианте использован параметр input [datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local), во втором параметр input [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) через функцию [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), используя шаблон `Год-месяц-день`

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?=strtotime($article['date'])?>"> <!-- Запись со временем -->
<input type="date" value="<?=date('Y-m-d',$article['date'])?>"> <!-- Запись без времени -->
```